# Создание DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть некий UserControl, естественно являющийся DependencyObject'om для которого нужно создать свое DependencyProperty по типу такого:

```
<my:TLBUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,25,0,0" x:Name="tLBUserControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

где    `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` является DependencyProperty. Как это сделать наиболее правильно. Покидайте хороших статей на эту тему, а еще лучше примеры кода. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Обычное свойство зависимостей (также влияющее на собственную перерисовку в примере). В конструкторе FrameworkPropertyMetadata можно определить дополнительные настройки, такие как метод корректировки значения или обработки измененного значения. MSDN или книга "WPF 3.0-4.0 для профессионалов"

   ```
   #region Единичный размер (NormalSize)
   [Category("Group properties")]
   public Size NormalSize
   {
       get { return (Size)GetValue(NormalSizeProperty); }
       set { SetValue(NormalSizeProperty, value); }
   }
   public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalSizeProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("NormalSize", typeof(Size), typeof(GroupPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Size(200, 190)) { AffectsArrange = true, AffectsMeasure = true });

   #endregion
   ```
2. Есть очень полезный тип зависимых свойств - т.н. Attatched Property. Смысл такой, как например, Grid.Row или Canvas.Top. его можно "прикрепить" к любому DependencyObject и затем его использовать уже непосредственно в контроле. При инициализации требуется чуть больше кода, но он идейно обоснован и без него никак. Вот пример Attatched Property.

   ```
   static GroupPanel() // - статический конструктор класса
   {
       var metadata =
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata();
       metadata.AffectsParentArrange = true; - различные атрибуты
       metadata.AffectsParentMeasure = true;
       BreakBeforeProperty =
           DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
           "ColumnBreakBefore",
           typeof(bool), typeof(GroupPanel),
           metadata);
   }
   #region Свойство разрыва (BreakBefore)
   public static DependencyProperty BreakBeforeProperty;

   public static void SetColumnBreakBefore(UIElement element,
       Boolean value)
   {
       element.SetValue(BreakBeforeProperty, value);
   }
   public static Boolean GetColumnBreakBefore(UIElement element)
   {
       return (bool)element.GetValue(BreakBeforeProperty);
   }
   #endregion
   ```

Замечание по использованию. Чтобы Attatched Property работало правильно и распознавалась системой, необходимо соблюдать соглашение по наименованию статичестих методов

`public static тип свойства Get(Set)имя свойства(тип объекта)`. 
Надеюсь это понятно. В моем примере это

`public static Boolean GetColumnBreakBefore(UIElement element) {  }`